# Camera flutter Preview

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]When I opening camera in Pixel, Camera View is different but in phone device its working fine please help me to solve.
The camera position in the phone with respect to tab is different.
So, The images stay vertical and don't rotate the 90degrees with the phone.

```
 return new AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
    child: new CameraPreview(
      controller,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Your description is a bit difficult to understand, at least for me. I guess adding screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: ok, I can explain more.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to setup roations for camera

Comment: Can you send me some hints?

Comment: What do you expect to look or behave differently? Is it that it doesn't use the full screen? Can you also add a screenshot how you want it to look like "in phone device its working fine"

Comment: Yes on the phone it is working fine. You can see my pic is vertical direction is should horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **image_picker: "^0.4.5"** for get camera image.

var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

Comment: Ya thanks, but this problem is before picking any image

Comment: can you send me some more detail?